# CSS :hover issue

Tags: html, css, css-animations, pseudo-class, keyframe

I got this problem with my pseudo classes,
i have a dropdownlist with anchor taggs in it, like so:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="dropdown-wrapper">
    <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" id="toggle-dropdown">Het 10-stappenplan <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap1">Stap 1 - Een oriënterend gesprek</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap2">Stap 2 - De AirAware Quickscan</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap3">Stap 3 - Uw ambitie, wensen en eisen</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap4">Stap 4 - Ons Advies</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap5">Stap 5 - Uw keuze</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap6">Stap 6 - Het ontwerp en de planning</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap7">Stap 7 - De realisatie</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap8">Stap 8 - Het beheer en onderhoud</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap9">Stap 9 - De periodieke controle</a></li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap10">Stap 10 - Sale &amp; Leaseback</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then i got my CSS:

```
.links .dropdown-menu li a.menulink{
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 260px;
}

.links .dropdown-menu li a.menulink:hover {
    animation: textColorfade 2s ease forwards !important;
    -webkit-animation: textColorfade 2s ease forwards !important;
    color:black;
    padding: 8px 5 8px 20px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes textColorfade {
    from { 
    color: white !important; 
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 10px !important;
    }

    to { 
    color: black !important; 
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 10px !important;
   }
   }
```

for some reason when the link is visited it doesnt do the keyframe animation anymore, i believe neither when its active, can anyone explain me why and maybe how i can fix this problem

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of the second line of the second rule. That, and you haven't declared your keyframes *without* the vendor prefix.

Comment: still not working. fixed the ; and the vendor prefix is -webkit- right ? if so i also fixed that

Comment: Style the anchors without hover etc. So just use something like `.dropdown-menu li a {color: #ff0000;}`

Comment: i did, just not the :active and :visited

Comment: get rid of the .links prefix

It's non-existent in the code you've posted

Comment: @DennisHeitinga what exactly you want on hover it will show list of submenu right?

Comment: can you show your expected output as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links cannot have **multiple** pseudo-classes / states so

```
a:visited:hover {
}
```

is not possible.

I suspect what you are after is a transition **not** an animation.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `.links` class in html:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group links" id="dropdown-wrapper"> <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" id="toggle-dropdown">Het 10-stappenplan <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap1">Stap 1 - Een oriënterend gesprek</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap2">Stap 2 - De AirAware Quickscan</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap3">Stap 3 - Uw ambitie, wensen en eisen</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap4">Stap 4 - Ons Advies</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap5">Stap 5 - Uw keuze</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap6">Stap 6 - Het ontwerp en de planning</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap7">Stap 7 - De realisatie</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap8">Stap 8 - Het beheer en onderhoud</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap9">Stap 9 - De periodieke controle</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap10">Stap 10 - Sale &amp; Leaseback</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.links .dropdown-menu li a.menulink { //here you missed `.` in links
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 260px;
}
.links .dropdown-menu li a.menulink:hover {
    animation: textColorfade 2s ease forwards !important;
    -webkit-animation: textColorfade 2s ease forwards !important color:black;
    padding: 8px 5 8px 20px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
@-webkit-keyframes textColorfade {
    from {
        color: white !important;
        padding: 8px 5px 8px 10px !important;
    }
    to {
        color: black !important;
        padding: 8px 5px 8px 10px !important;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/731/

Comment: if you click a link then the animation stops working

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here is the working demo on hover functionality http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/625hv792/1/

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group links" id="dropdown-wrapper"> <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" id="toggle-dropdown">Het 10-stappenplan <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap1">Stap 1 - Een oriënterend gesprek</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap2">Stap 2 - De AirAware Quickscan</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap3">Stap 3 - Uw ambitie, wensen en eisen</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap4">Stap 4 - Ons Advies</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap5">Stap 5 - Uw keuze</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap6">Stap 6 - Het ontwerp en de planning</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap7">Stap 7 - De realisatie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap8">Stap 8 - Het beheer en onderhoud</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap9">Stap 9 - De periodieke controle</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menulink" href="?p=stap10">Stap 10 - Sale &amp; Leaseback</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.links .dropdown-menu li a.menulink {
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
    color: #000;
    width: 260px;
}
.links .dropdown-menu {
    animation: textColorfade 2s ease forwards;
    -webkit-animation: textColorfade 2s ease forwards;             
    color:black;
    display:none;
}
.links:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
}
```